# How can I turn an array of keys into an array of values?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash like

```
hash = { 'burger': 2, 'kebab': 5, 'pizza': 10 }
```

and I have an array of its keys like

```
['burger', 'burger', 'pizza']
```

How would I create an array of the corresponding values? Would `inject` method be the best method to sum value array together?

Comment: The hash syntax is wrong.

Comment: if old version of Ruby is used.

Comment: What you have as the array of keys is wrong.

Comment: so I can't use strings as key names? I have to use symbols? good to know

Comment: You **can** use either strings or symbols as hash keys, but you **are** using symbols, not strings here.

Comment: If you think my second comment is not true, then can you explain the logic behind the array you have? What is the relation between `hash` and your array?

Comment: it's the colon isn't it? I assumed that colons and hash rockets were interchangeable but I'm wrong aren't I? so the correct syntax would be {'burger' => 2, 'kebab' => 5, 'pizza' => 10} ?

Comment: @Mundedx yes, it is the colon which makes the keys symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you don't even need to prepare the key arrays.

- To get the keys: `hash.keys`
- To get the values: `hash.values`

If you want only certain values or values in certain order, then

```
a = [:burger, :pizza]
hash.values_at(*a) # => [2, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for help, i think i can incorporate this into my project nicely!!

Comment: To answer @Munded's last question, add `.reduce(:+)` to get the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` as you've particularly said of wanting value of particular key in an array in a particular order. Else, you can use `hash.values`

```
arr = ['burger', 'burger', 'pizza']
results = arr.map { |key| hash[key] }
```